# Problem creating a new publication without parents

Tags: content-manager, 2013-sp1

I'm trying to create a new publication in Content Manager in SDL Tridion 2013 SP1. This new publication have not parents publications. When I try to save and exit, I get this error:

> Unable to save item.
>   The transaction associated with the current connection has completed
>   but has not been disposed. The transaction must be disposed before the
>   connection can be used to execute SQL statements.

If I try to create a publication that inherits from another publication, the process works fine.

Can somebody help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is usually a sign that the transaction is taking too long, probably because creating a _completely new_ publication needs more time to set up defaults and whatever. Other answers in this site point at database maintenance as the best starting point.

Comment: In my case, the database has been migrated from a SDL Tridion 2011 SP1. Maybe the problem can be caused by this?

Comment: That should not be a problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Nuno and Shiva stated, this may be a problem with the database, and if it comes from a migrated database, what we have suffer many times is the existence of orphan elements in the queue tables.

The first thing to do is to update the name of the host in the **Trustees** table, but one important thing to do when a Database is migrated from one host to another is to check the **Queue** tables, we used a script like this for an Oracle database:

```
Declare
ServerName varchar2(20);
BEGIN
  ServerName:='<hostname>';
 delete from TCMDBUSER.QUEUE_MESSAGES where CREATION_HOST_NAME = ServerName;

 delete from TCMDBUSER.QUEUE_FILTERS where QUEUE_CONSUMER_ID in 
(select ID from TCMDBUSER.QUEUE_CONSUMERS where HOST = ServerName);

delete from TCMDBUSER.QUEUE_CONSUMERS where HOST = ServerName;
END;
```

(changing "hostname" with the name of the old host)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you very much Raúl, I tried what you said in Queue tables and it works fine!

Also thanks a lot to Shiva and Nuno.

Comment: I forgot to say it was a Oracle database.

Comment: Glad to know that problem is resolved! If your QUEUE tables is holding values from an upgraded database, it indicates that there is definitely room for additional improvements. I would still suggest allocating sometime and look at some regular maintenance tasks for your Tridion databases.

Answer (score 4):

As Nuno highlighted, it is clearly a problem with your database maintenance. A good starting point would be to review the documentation [HERE](https://sdltridionworld.com/articles/MaintainingSDLTridiondatabases.aspx).

The AnalyzeStats.sql and RebuildIndexes.sql are also recommended. Refer Chris's article [HERE](http://chrismills.eu/tridion/database.aspx) too.

To solve your problem, you can try to create your orphan publication a couple of times and it could succeed but I would definitely look into database maintenance ASAP.